# How to dynamically add sheet reference in a range in Googlesheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to fetch the sheet name from another column and put in inside the formula.

[Here is picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vu2M2.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take this opportunity to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13196995/daniel-h)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=COUNTA(INDIRECT(A2&"!G2:G1000"))
```

**Reference:**

- [INDIRECT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en)